# Which one to choose? I am about to encrypt my USB Stick using Truecrypt

Tags: usb-flash-drive, truecrypt

Which one to choose? I am about to encrypt my USB Stick using Truecrypt, but I am prompted with these options, although I guess it's just the same because I only have one USB stick attached and it only has 1 partition?

1.)
Removable Disk 1:           1.8 GB

2.)
\Device\Harddisk1\Partition1    F:  1.8 GB  MY_USB

I encountered this in Volume Location (Select Device dialog box)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you format your question so the two options are clear? Seems odd the disk has no partition, you sure about that, because it clearly does.

Comment: I mean, only one partition because I did not do any partitioning, I just formatted it using Windows.

Comment: The device clearly only has a single partition.  You want to select the second option.

Comment: you may want to just consider using a file volume instead of a partition. its easier to manage if nothing else.

Comment: Okay, i will be using file volume, so i still can save Truecrypt Portable extracted program alongside my file volume inside the USB. I will be making two USBs, one is for back-up, will be putting there all my important files, mostly banks and paypals passwords. Help me which algorithm and hash to choose: ALGORITHM: AES, Serpent, Twofish, AES-Twofish, Serpent-AES, Twofish-Serpent, AES-Twofish-Serpent, Serpent-Twofish-AES... And also HASH: RIPEMD-160, SHA-512, Whirlpool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first option, as Truecrypt will delete the existing partition on your device to format it with the proprietary format.